# Gibt es eine gängige Übersetzung von »premature optimisation«?

Tags: english-to-german, word-usage

Im Englischen ist *premature optimisation* ein feststehender Begriff für übereifrige Laufzeit- oder Speicheroptimierungen beim Programmieren. Gibt es einen gängigen oder gar etablierten Begriff, der dafür im Deutschen verwendet wird? Es geht mir letztlich um ein Stichwort, das ich jemandem (ggf. neben dem englischen Originalbegriff) nennen kann und unter dem man möglichst viele Informationen zu dem Thema findet.

Folgende denkbare Übersetzungen habe ich in eine Suchmaschine gefüttert und keine zufriedenstellende Anzahl an Ergebnissen erhalten (was aber nicht notwendigerweise heißt, dass sie ausgeschlossene Antworten sind – vielleicht wird über dieses Thema einfach wenig auf Deutsch gesprochen):

- übereifrige Optimierung
- vorschnelle Optimierung
- vorreife Optimierung
- frühzeitige Optimierung (zusammen mit *Programmieren* als Suchkriterium, da viele der Ergebnisse nichts hiermit zu tun hatten)
- verfrühte Optimierung

Beachte: **Die Frage lautet nicht**, wie man den Begriff übersetzen könnte oder was die treffendste Übersetzung ist. Es geht mir auch nicht darum, ob man jetzt eine deutsche Übersetzung oder den englischen Originalbegriff verwenden sollte.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass ich das jemals übersetzt gesehen oder gehört habe. Von den Möglichkeiten, die du vorschlägst, ergeben nur "vorschnell" und "verfrüht" Sinn.

Comment: In Anlehnung an `Vorauseilender Gehorsam` würde mir Vorauseilende Optimierung gefallen. Das impliziert auch die oftmalige Sinnlosigkeit. Um danach zu suchen würde ich aber die englische Variante bevorzugen..

Comment: Besser als die von dir genannten Optionen finde ich "voreilige Optimierung", aber ein etablierter Begriff ist das auch nicht.

Comment: "vorzeitige Optimierung" (wie in dirkts Antwort) und "zu frühe Optimierung" liefern definitv Ergebnisse https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22vorzeitige+optimierung%22 .
Ansonsten einfach "premature optimization" suchen und Ergebnisse nach Sprache limitieren, oder eine deutsche Phrase wie "vermeiden" dazu schreiben.

Comment: Anstatt in Fett hervorzuheben, was die Frage nicht ist, eventuell solltest du die Frage besser klären. Denn dann ist die Antwort meist recht einfach zu finden.

Comment: Die Frage basiert auf einem Mangel an Überlegung. Bei einem wörtlichen Zitat hat man in der Ursprungssprache eine eindeutige Phrase vor sich, die wörtlich zitiert wird. Gibt es für einen Begriff mehrere mögliche Übersetzungen, dann kann jeder Übersetzer zu einer anderen Variante greifen. Eine solche Ausdrucksvielfalt kann es in der Quellsprache genauso geben, aber da ist es als Zitat eben fixiert. Es müsste schon einen normativen Übersetzer geben, und sehr viele Verwender müssten den Ausdruck nur von diesem Übersetzer, nicht im Original kennen, damit er sich so festsetzen könnte.

Comment: @DisplayName: Da ich trotz des Hervorhebens, was die Frage nicht ist, eine entsprechende Antwort erhalten habe, sehe ich mich in dieser Entscheidung bestätigt. Ansonsten: Was ist denn nicht klar?

Comment: @userunknown: *Premature optimisation* wird mittlerweile durchaus außerhalb dieses Zitats verwendet – ich habe z. B. erst bei der Recherche zu dieser Frage herausgefunden, dass es einem Zitat entstammt. Davon abgesehen können sich Übersetzungen sehr schnell etablieren. Zum Beispiel wenn ein Standardwerk für Programmierer oder eine Wikipedia-Seite dem Begriff einen Abschnitt gewidmet und eine treffende Übersetzung verwendet hätte.

Comment: Da "premature optimisation" ein Wortspiel sein könnte, das klanglich an "premature ejaculation" erinnern soll, bietet sich dementsprechend eine Übersetzung mit "vorzeitige Optimierung" an.

Answer (score 5):

Da das Originalzitat ("premature optimazation is the root of all evil") auf Englisch ist, gibt es keine festen etablierten Begriff (zumindest kenne ich keinen), nur Übersetzungen oder das Original (Informatiker reden sowieso viel Englisch). "Vorzeitig" und "verfrüht" sind mir in diesem Zusammenhang als übliche Übersetzungen bekannt. "Übereifrig" und "vorschnell" habe ich noch nie gehört, "Vorreif" ist falsch.

Zusammen mit "Wurzel allen Übels" liefert Google wahrscheinlich bessere Ergebnisse. :-)

Comment: "Optimierung", zusammen mit "Wurzel allen Übels" liefert bessere Ergebnisse. "Wurzel allen Übels" allein liefert Geld, Religion und Liebe. ;)

Comment: "Informatiker sprechen sowieso viel Englisch" absolut richtig. Ich muss immer erst im Kopf zurück-übersetzen wenn ich mal IT-Literatur auf deutsch lese.

Answer (score -1):

If you go by the wikipedia entry that comes up when searching for premature optimization, there is no established word yet.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization

This means it is a "**Fachbegriff**" which originated in a foreign language and should be used.  In this case your colleague/friend should search for premature optimization.

---

Why?

The standard translation "verfrüht" does not have the same connotations.

Premature means before it is ripe or mature(d).

So in extend it means you should let something (the codebase) ripe and or settle 
before you spend/waste time optimizing it prematurely.

Then be the best German translation I can come up with would be:

> Verfrühte Optimierung unreifer Software.

As you can see it is a sentence and not just two words.

So in my opinion the english original is superior because it expresses the same sentiment more briefly.

---

If you insist on using German words only I'd say stick with "Verfrühter Optimierung".

- Or "Vorzeitiger Optimierung". (almost the same as premature)
- Or "Vorreifer Optimierung" (pretty much the same as premature, unusual but possible)

---

I checked in Google and the results, using "Verfrühte Optimierung" look promising. The first entry is exactly about this topic. 87.000 Results are not to shabby either.

[Google: verfrühte optimierung](https://www.google.ie/search?rls=en&q=verfr%C3%BChte+optimierung&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ZrLYU9PAKaP8ywPls4DIBQ)

If you search for **"verfrühte optimierung"** there are still 244 results left. Some of them point to the english original phrase.

> **"Optimieren 24.1.3 The root of all evil "Premature optimization is the root of all evil""**

[Google: "verfrühte optimierung"](https://www.google.ie/search?rls=en&q=verfr%C3%BChte+optimierung&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ZrLYU9PAKaP8ywPls4DIBQ#q=%22verfr%C3%BChte+optimierung%22&rls=en)

BUT

[Google: "Vorzeitige Optimierung"](https://www.google.ie/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Vorreifer%20Optimierung&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=5AXbU6erLLSu7AaL7YDQAw#q=%22vorzeitige%20optimierung%22&rls=en) beats that with 1020 entries.

While

[Google: "Vorreife Optimierung"](https://www.google.ie/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22Vorreife%20Optimierung%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=sAbbU_2NMLTB7AbJp4H4CA) only returns this very page you are reading.

YET

[Google: Vorreife Optimierung](https://www.google.ie/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22Vorreife%20Optimierung%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=sAbbU_2NMLTB7AbJp4H4CA#q=Vorreife%20Optimierung&rls=en) results in some nice non IT-Specific results for this concept. Like unripe food and how to let it mature before processing it. (An already invented wheel?)

---

Other examples for borrowed words "Fachbegriffe" in the IT-space are:

- E-Mail
- Website
- Personal Computer

You could search for elektronische Nachricht/E-Nachricht or Netz-Seite/Netzpräsenz. If you are intent on looking for German phrases. But again they are not the originals and are less common.

---

It might take some time before the word(s)/phrase are assimilated and Germanized and for example something like Courier --> Kurier happens.

Until then. Stick with the most popular expression for research.

Comment: Mir ist auch nicht bekannt, dass sich "premature optimization" mittlerweile zum Fachbegriff gemausert hat. Schon allein deshalb, weil sich niemand darüber einig ist, wie man denn "premature" genau definieren sollte. Eigentlich ist es ja nur ein Aphorismus von Donald Knuth.

Comment: Nur zur Klarstellung: Es geht mir nicht darum, auf Biegen und Brechen einen deutschen Begriff zu verwenden. 244 Suchergebnisse (die nicht alle de facto dasselbe zu sein scheinen) ist zwar bisher die beste Ausbeute, aber in diesem Kontext noch nicht so viel, dass ich von einem gängigen Begriff ausgehen würde.

Comment: "Premature optimization" ist kein Fachbegriff, sondern die Kombination 2er gängiger Begriffe in konventioneller Weise und bedeutet das, was ein Attribut mit einem Substantiv immer bedeutet. "Schnelles Pferd" ist auch kein Fachbegriff aus dem Reitsport. Es gibt auch keinen Grund den Ausdruck auf das Programmieren zu beschränken. Bei einer Übersetzung, die im D. viele Varianten zulässt, geht auch weder etwas verloren, noch entsteht Raum für Missverständnisse. Die Beispiele Website und E-Mail passen gar nicht - obw. mit Netzauftritt o. Netzpräsenz auch für Website geschmeidige Alt. existieren.

Answer (score -2):

Das kann man ganz einfach mit **Fehloptimierung** übersetzen.

Überleg mal, was der Spruch eigentlich besagen will: »Premature optimization = root of all evil.« Da kommt ein neunmalkluger Juniorentwickler und frickelt sich ewig einen ab, um irgendeine völlig randständige und bedeutungslose Stelle zu tunen … Bringt am Ende nix außer mehr Komplexität. Ist also eine Fehloptimierung, womit zwar nicht der zeitliche Aspekt ausgedrückt wird, aber auf den kommt es hier meiner Meinung nach auch gar nicht an; ebenso gut könnte der Spruch nämlich lauten »*Unwarranted* oder *uncalled-for* optimization is the root of all evil.«

Noch eine Regel dazu von mir: **»Verbatim translation is the root of all ugly.«**

Comment: Mal abgesehen davon, dass ich nicht danach gefragt habe, wie *premature optimisation* übersetzt werden **kann**, sondern wie es übersetzt **wird**, halte ich *Fehloptimierung* für eine schlechte Übersetzung, da weder jede Fehloptimierung eine Premature Optimisation ist (ich kann auch laufzeitkritische Stellen verschlimmbesseren oder sonstwelche Fehler begehen), noch jede Premature Optimization eine Fehloptimierung ist (wenn ich an einer Stelle optimiere, die sich erst im Nachhinein als tatsächlich laufzeitkritisch herausstellt, ist es keine Fehloptimierung, wohl aber Premature Optimisation).

Comment: Ich glaub, jetzt wird es etwas haarspalterisch. Es heißt »root of all evil«. Das ist mehr als deutlich. Natürlich ist das per Definition eine Fehloptimierung. Wenn du unbedingt den zeitlichen Aspekt brauchst, dann sagst du halt *voreilige* oder *vorzeitige* Optimierung.

Comment: Dass Premature Optimisation wird im berühmten Zitat (welches außerdem zweifellos kontextbezogen ist) als Wurzel allen Übels identifiziert. Das heißt aber nicht, dass die Begriffe gleichzusetzen sind. Das ist in etwa so, als würde man *organised* mit *schlecht* übersetzen, weil irgendwer mal gesagt hat: »Organised religion is the root of all evil.«